# ANGULAR -2 Component Loading Order

Tags: angular2-routing

I am working on an Angular Project, I have two component transcationlist, transcationlistdetail both components are on a single page.

My problem is when I am loading these components, I need to load these component in a sequence e.g. first I want to load transcationlist and then transcationlistdetail.

Is there any mechanism in Angular 2/4 to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not right to make two components in the same page which is one depending on another one.

you can make one component inside the other one

```
@Component({
   selector:'app-root',
   template: ` <app-a></app-a>`
})

export class Root {}
-------------------------------------------------------
@Component({
   selector:'app-a',
   template: ` <app-b></app-b>`
})

export class A {}
----------------------------------
@Component({
   selector:'app-b',
   template: ``
})

export class B {}
```

here the component root will be loaded and when it starts in rendering the component A will start it's life cycle you can write all the logic in 
ngOnInit function which will executed before rendering html code and we will guarantee that any logic in component A will be loaded before Component B

Answer (score 0):

If we cant used dependent component, then what is use of component in single page